# Matlab/Octave: Function with array and number as argument -> subscript error

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, octave

As Octave does not seem to bring a Gauss function for 1D or 2D by default I tried to define those functions by myself.

I started of with the definition

```
function [result] = Gauss(x,[x0 sigma])
result = 1/(sqrt(2*pi*sigma^2))*exp(-1(x-x0)^2/2*sigma^2)
end
```

which resulted in a subscript error

```
error: subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals
```

I Tried to modify the function definition as follows:

```
function [result] = Gauss(x,[x0 sigma])
```

as I found a function gaussmf from Matlab, where you can pass an array x and single numbers in x0 and sigma. Unfortunately I still get a subscription error with that.

So my question is: How can I pass an array and additional non-array arguments in this case? 
I thought this would be rather automatic, but does not seem to be... ;)

Thanks

Comment: GNU Octave has `normpdf()` for the 1D case. You can't define functions that way. Please read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error comes from:

```
exp(-1(x-x0)^2/2*sigma^2)
```

and I suspect you want

```
exp(-(x-x0)^2/2*sigma^2)
```

instead. As you have written it you are trying to index `1` with `x-x0`. In fact, if `x` is a vector, you probably want:

```
exp(-(x-x0).^2/2*sigma^2)
```